# How can I completely circumvent floating point inconsistancies? (Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin, math, precision

For your information, I **am** aware that not all fractions can be converted to decimals. There's just nothing you can do about that. What I would like to know is if there is a specific way to avoid floating point precision errors when you know the repeating decimal will eventually be canceled out. Like `var num = 3 * Math.PI; var newNum = num/Math.PI`. `newNum` should equal 3, not 2.999999999 or 3.0000000012

I am writing a program in Kotlin to standardize units in my project. Currently, I am working on an Angle class with the options of degrees and radians. Naturally, this class has a conversion function. When I ran some unit tests, I noticed that they were all failing because of what seems to be a floating point division error. By the way, all of the numbers I am using are doubles.

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :60.0
Actual   :59.99999999999999
```

I was wondering if there is any way to circumvent something like this in Kotlin. After doing some research, I have found that Java has some sort of BigDecimal class that you can *technically* use in Kotlin code, but I want to do this natively. The code using Java is clunky and, I'm assuming, very space inefficient. Ideally I wouldn't even need a separate data type because there was some clever bit of mathematics to circumvent the whole problem. Just for reference on what is going wrong, I will put what I think the program is doing below.

```
val rad = Radians(Math.PI / 3.0)
// I think the compiler immediately converts this to a decimal value.
// 1.0471975512...
// Then it tries to convert it to degrees
val finalDegVal = 1.0471975512 * 180 / Math.PI
// 60.00000000019, for example (depends on how many decimal places it's calculating)
assertEquals(60.0, 60.00000000019)
```

And then the error occurs

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :60.0
Actual   :59.99999999999999
```

I am wondering if there is anything I can do about this. I've known about floating point errors and I know I can just round but I'm sure there's a more elegant and mathematically accurate solution. Any ideas?

Finally, here is the code in case it is relevant.

```
enum class Angles {
    DEGREES,
    RADIANS;
}

abstract class Angle(private val rotation: Double, private val unit: Angles) {
    private val degreeConversionRatio: Double = 1.0
    private val radianConversionRatio: Double = 180.0/Math.PI

    fun toDegrees(): Double = when(unit) {
        Angles.DEGREES -> rotation * degreeConversionRatio
        Angles.RADIANS -> rotation * radianConversionRatio
    }
    fun toRadians(): Double = toDegrees() * 1/radianConversionRatio
    override fun equals(other: Any?) = (other is Angle) && this.toDegrees() == other.toDegrees()
    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        var result = toDegrees().hashCode()
        result = 31 * result + unit.hashCode()
        return result
    }
}

class Degrees(rotation: Double): Angle(rotation, Angles.DEGREES)
class Radians(rotation: Double): Angle(rotation, Angles.RADIANS)
```

Comment: A typical solution is to compare the difference against a tiny number. `abs(60 - 60.00000000019) < 1e-14`.

Comment: This is a kind of fundamental problem with floats, as you have said. My advice is to use rational numbers, for which arithmetic is exact. (From what I can tell, BigDecimal arithmetic is not exact. Maybe someone can say more about that.) A quick web search finds a lot of implementations in Java, I didn't look for Kotlin, and I don't know if there is an implementation which is considered best or the conventional solution. Good luck and have fun.

Comment: I cant use arithmetic numbers when I'm using radians. I have to use PI.

Comment: There is indeed a clever bit of mathematics and... it's a separate data type. Except nowhere near Java or Kotlin standard library. You'll need to read a scientific paper instead: https://blog.acolyer.org/2020/10/02/toward-an-api-for-the-real-numbers/. There may be others as well, but this is the one I know of that would fix your problem.